# Avoid line break before page number in the index

Tags: xetex, indexing, xindy

This is a bit of a contrived example, as the real one depends on specific fonts I can't post here. MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[unbalanced,columns=3,justific=RaggedRight,columnsep=70pt]{idxlayout}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
text\index{this-should-break}
\index{thisss-should-break}
\index{this-one-does-break}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I'd like:

[image]

IDX-File:

```
\indexentry{this-should-break|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{thisss-should-break|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{this-one-does-break|hyperpage}{1}
```

IND-File:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item this-one-does-break, \hyperpage{1}
  \item this-should-break, \hyperpage{1}
  \item thisss-should-break, \hyperpage{1}

\end{theindex}
```

I'd like to avoid the line break before the page number for the second entry. I don't know if that's possible at all. I assume I'm looking for a solution that produces something like `\item this-should-break,~\hyperpage{1}`, but then again, `\hyperpage` might internally do something to still make it break.

**EDIT**

As I now not only found a regular but also a xindy solution, I retagged this accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's actually pretty easy to achieve, if you know how. The key points are:

- usage of package `imakeidx` instead of `makeidx`
- creation of a style file that redefines `delim_0`

test.ist:

```
delim_0 ",~"
```

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[unbalanced,columns=3,justific=RaggedRight,columnsep=70pt]{idxlayout}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeindex[options=-s test.ist]
\begin{document}
text\index{this-should-break}
\index{thisss-should-break}
\index{this-one-does-break}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Resulting ind-File:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item this-one-does-break,~\hyperpage{1}
  \item this-should-break,~\hyperpage{1}
  \item thisss-should-break,~\hyperpage{1}

\end{theindex}
```

Output:

[image]

**Here's how to do it for xindy:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[unbalanced,columns=3,justific=RaggedRight,columnsep=70pt]{idxlayout}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeindex[options=-M test.xdy]
\begin{document}
text\index{this-should-break}
\index{thisss-should-break}
\index{this-one-does-break}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

test.xdy:

```
(markup-locclass-list :open ",~~")
```

Output:

[image]